# Why won't 'lighter' and 'bolder' font weights work?

Tags: html, css, angular, fonts, ionic2

I am creating an Ionic app and I want to use the custom font 'Rubik'. I have imported 'lighter' and 'bolder' font weights but they don't seem to work - wherever I add the style it just used the normal font weight. Here's the code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Light.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Bold.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Black.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik');
```

These are placed in the variables.scss file. At the moment I can only use lighter/bolder if I assign it to a new font family as normal. Lighter and bolder work fine for the default fonts installed with ionic (roboto, noto-sans). Any ideas?

Comment: I think `font-weight` is not really needed anymore, as the weight is already defined by the font. Just use a unique name for each font and it should be good to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would import/load it like this, to only get the desired font weights:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

Defining the font-face like this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Light.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Bold.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('#{$font-path}/Rubik-Black.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And using it like this :

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

fig {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

you can also create a function/mixin in scss or define variables to have easier access to these font weights like so :

```
@mixin fontRubik($weight) {
  @if($weight == 'bold') {
     font-weight: 700;
  } @elseif($weight == 'black') {
     font-weight: 900;
  } @elseif($weight == 'light') {
     font-weight: 300;
  } @else {
     font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`lighter` means *One font weight lighter than the parent element (among the available weights of the font).*

`bolder` means *One font weight heavier than the parent element (among the available weights of the font).*

They are **relative** weights.

When you are defining a new font-face, if you are defining it for a given weight, then it has to be an absolute weight. There is nothing for it to be relative to.

This is why `lighter` and `bolder` are not listed in the [valid values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#descdef-font-weight) and why [your CSS will be reported as invalid](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input).